# f:Lebesgue measurable function ⇆　∀ε>0, ∃g:continuous function s.t. λ({x|f(x)≠g(x)})<ε

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-measure

my friend told me this non-obvious prop.
I think false,but I can't understand.
Does anyone solve this problem?

Comment: The "$\Rightarrow$" implication seems to be [Lusin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem).

Comment: use Egoroff's theorem. There is a sequence f_n of contn functions converging a.e to our function. We can extract  on a certain subset of E of measure m(E)-epselon a uniformly convergent subsequence. By uniform convergence the new limit is continuous. etc.